# What is the equivalent label control in an android device?

Tags: java, android, oop

Anyone knows the equivalent of a label control in an android device? Text box or something similar?

Comment: It's `TextView`. You should have researched a bit. It's very basic question.

Comment: came close with text box, thanks

Comment: @user1463680 - From next time onwards, kindly google/research before posting a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is TextView.

Read this : [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

It displays text to the user.